# Material UI: prop type `component` is invalid

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to update the material ui to the latest(4.1.1) in my project.
I am getting lot of same warnings in the console, for all of the Material UI components.

Like:

Warning: Failed prop type: ForwardRef(Paper): prop type `component` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.

Comment: Without seeing any code for what triggers this error and without a reproduction of the problem (e.g. CodeSandbox), my best guess is that you are pulling in an old version of the prop-types package (current version is 15.7.2) which doesn't support PropTypes.elementType.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have updated the prop-types version to 15.7.2. But no luck.